# Why any normal distribution has an MLR?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

On *Statistical Inference* exercise 8.25, it reads "As $\bar{X}$ is sufficient and its distribution has an MLR (see Exercise 8.25)", I'm wondering if anyone could give a brief hint on this? Thanks!!!

Comment: Just got the answer and appended it following the question!

Comment: Please instead post the answer as an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will remain open and contribute to clogging the system.

Comment: Sure. Will do. However, it may feel like I'm posting something for myself.

Comment: Quite to the contrary. The answers posted here add value to the site for the entire community. It's explicitly encouraged to answer your own questions (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). (Note the nice formulation "others (including yourself)" :-)

Answer (score 0):

We only need to prove 

 Suppose $X\textrm{~}\mathscr{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for some $\mu$, $\sigma\in\mathbb{R}$. We have $f_X(x|\mu')/f_X(x|\mu)$ is monotonously increasing in $x$, where $\mu'>\mu$ and $f_X(\bullet|\mu)$ is the probability density function of $X$ given $\mu$. 

 In fact, since $f_X(x|\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\textrm{exp}(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$, we have 
$$
\frac{f_X(x|\mu')}{f_X(x|\mu)}=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\textrm{exp}(-\frac{(x-\mu')^2}{2\sigma^2})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\textrm{exp}(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})}
=\textrm{exp}(\frac{(x-\mu)^2-(x-\mu')^2}{2\sigma^2})
=\textrm{exp}(\frac{(\mu'-\mu)(2x-\mu-\mu')}{2\sigma^2})
$$, which is monotonously increasing because $\mu'>\mu$.